# Bootstrap 5 float-end causing issue with flex elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

When I add the class float-end it pushes the button to right but the div tags next to that comes front of it.

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-7 bg-white shadow-sm rounded-3 mx-3 ">
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-2 mr-0">
      Edit  <i class="bi bi-pencil"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex p-2 justify-content-between border-bottom">
    <div class="fw-bold">Pan no</div>
    <div class="text-secondary">not added</div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex p-2 justify-content-between border-bottom">
    <div class="fw-bold">Birthdate</div>
    <div class="text-secondary">not added</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Floats are generally to be avoided in modern layout. Bootstrap provides all the flex utilities you'd need to achieve the same outcome.

Comment: Please accept your answer to resolve this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the "clearfix" class to button's parent div.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-7 bg-white shadow-sm rounded-3 mx-3 ">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-2 mr-0">
      Edit  <i class="bi bi-pencil"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex p-2 justify-content-between border-bottom">
    <div class="fw-bold">Pan no</div>
    <div class="text-secondary">not added</div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex p-2 justify-content-between border-bottom">
    <div class="fw-bold">Birthdate</div>
    <div class="text-secondary">not added</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, in the overview section
[Float - Bootstrap v5.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/float/)

> Please be aware float utilities have no effect on flex items.

Note that **float** will will make it pop to the left-most or right-most position in the parent element. so you **must** add **[clearfix](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/clearfix/)** to the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have two options for you

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- one options -->
<div class="col-md-7 bg-white shadow-sm rounded-3 mx-3 ">
   <div class="position-relative">
      <div class="position-absolute top-0 end-0">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-2 mr-0">
             Edit 
          </a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex p-2 justify-content-between border-bottom">
    <div class="fw-bold">Pan no</div>
    <div class="text-secondary">not added</div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex p-2 justify-content-between border-bottom">
    <div class="fw-bold">Birthdate</div>
    <div class="text-secondary">not added</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<!-- two options -->
<br>
<div class="col-md-7 bg-white shadow-sm rounded-3 mx-3 ">
  <div class="float-start col-10 p-2">
    <div class="d-flex p-2 justify-content-between border-bottom">
       <div class="fw-bold">Pan no</div>
       <div class="text-secondary">not added</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex p-2 justify-content-between border-bottom">
      <div class="fw-bold">Birthdate</div>
      <div class="text-secondary">not added</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="float-end col-2 p-2">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary d-flex justify-content-center align-self-center">
         Edit 
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="float-start col-12 p-2">
    <div class="d-flex p-2 justify-content-between border-bottom">
      <div class="fw-bold">Addres</div>
      <div class="text-secondary">not added</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex p-2 justify-content-between border-bottom">
      <div class="fw-bold">Zip Code</div>
      <div class="text-secondary">not added</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex p-2 justify-content-between border-bottom">
      <div class="fw-bold">City</div>
      <div class="text-secondary">not added</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```